# Fazer cálculo em coluna única no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Como é possível fazer um cálculo (exemplo: subtração) de valores somados de uma mesma coluna no PostgreSQL?

Exemplo da *query*:

```
DROP TABLE if exists saldo;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE saldo AS select a.usuario
from table as a;

SELECT a.usuario, pontosP, pontosN FROM
(SELECT COALESCE(sum(b.pontos), (0))
FROM t1 b WHERE ((b.status = 1) AND (b.usuario = a.usuario))) AS pontosP,

(SELECT COALESCE(sum(c.pontos), (0))
FROM t2 c
WHERE ((c.status = 0) AND (c.id_usuario = a.id_usuario))) AS pontosN;
```

Como fazer um cálculo usando os valores de retorno, exemplo: `(pontosP - pontosN)`?

Na verdade o `select` não esta funcionando corretamente porque ele não encontra a entrada `a` apesar dela existir na tabela temporária.

Comment: `from table as a` Existe essa sintaxe? Eu não conheço, tem alguma referência sobre ela? Isto seria para criar um alias para o nome tabela. E por que fazer isto. Se quer chamar a tabela de `a`, por que não chama ela de `a`? É uma tabela temporária. tem algo que eu não entendi?

Answer (score 1):

A sua questão está muito confusa mas parece que você quer agrupar pelo usuario:

```
select
    usuario,
    coalesce(sum(b.pontos), 0) as pontosp,
    coalesce(sum(c.pontos), 0) as pontosn,
    coalesce(sum(b.pontos), 0) - coalesce(sum(c.pontos), 0) as "diferença"
from
    saldo a
    inner join
    t1 b using (usuario)
    inner join
    t2 c using (usuario)
where b.status = 1 and c.status = 0
group by usuario
```